# MySQL select unique ID

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get a specific "inventory_update_stock_id" from list of IDs in a report. I used the following code line in my controller.

```
$inventory_update_stock_id = $this->input->post('inventory_update_stock_id');
```

The relevant "inventory_update_stock_id" selection showing as follows in my report.

```
<form action="<?= base_url('more/addMore/'.$row->inventory_update_stock_id) ?>" id="addMoreDetails" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
```

"more/addMore" is the name of my controller function.

When executing this option, the browser outs the following off-set error.
[image]

What might be missed by myself ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: Can you try `print_r($_POST);` and let me know, whether `inventory_update_stock_id` present in the data ?

Comment: @ Tushar. Yes. inventory_update_stock_id present in the data. And if I remove "DD", then returned data without inventory_update_stock_id.

Comment: You need to post enough so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @  Rohit Gupta. I had review the problem again. The error is stopped now. But the inventory_update_stock_id is returned the empty value.